# linux how to change directory in multiple machine with different hostname

Tags: linux, unix

I need to see server logs in different machines( around 20 ) and server logs are stored in location with hostname in their path ( I am using super putty).
So I dont have single command to chnage directory instead i have to do it individually.

With hostname command i can get m/c name but i am not able to use as vraible in my cd command.

```
>hostname
mymachinename
>cd /opt/$"hostname"/logs
no directory name /opt/hostname/logs
```

Any help on this?

Pardon me if its duplicate. I searched but didn't get any questions related to this.

Comment: should be cd /opt/$(hostname)/logs

Comment: any way a better aproach to do that quickly will be to export a FS on one of these servers and mount it on the rest... and after that do cat cd /opt/$(hostname)/desired.log >>  /mounted/fs/exported/from/server.
That way you can read the log on a single file instead on several files... Let me know if you need more explination on that aproach and I will help you

Comment: That's good thing..but then that wood require so many approvals.. :)
Anyways i only need for checking some specific patterns.

Comment: If that is the case ussing $(hostname) in Your script should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

shold be

```
cd /opt/$(hostname)
```

See..

```
root@mongodbServer1:~# cd /opt/$(hostname)
root@mongodbServer1:/opt/mongodbServer1# pwd
/opt/mongodbServer1
root@mongodbServer1:/opt/mongodbServer1#
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $HOSTNAME or $(hostname) or `hostname` (inverted quote) to retrieve the hostname.